# fslmaths subtraction function gives error: output can't be found

Tags: unix

the code will not create the output 'imdiff' but instead will say it can't find imdiff.

```
dyn896-105:intro sophiejacobs$ pwd
/Users/sophiejacobs/Downloads/preCourse/intro
dyn896-105:intro sophiejacobs$ ls
LThal_mask_func.nii.gz      filtered_func_data.nii.gz
LThal_mask_std.nii.gz       highres.nii.gz
bighead.nii.gz          image0.nii.gz
bvals               image1.nii.gz
cst2standard_73_46_26.nii.gz    newfmri.nii.gz
diffdata.nii.gz         standard.nii.gz
egepi.nii.gz            structural.nii.gz
egfmri.nii.gz           sub3m0.nii.gz
example_func.nii.gz     thresh_zstat1.nii.gz
example_func2highres.mat    wrapped.nii.gz
example_func2standard.mat
dyn896-105:intro sophiejacobs$ fslmaths image0 -sub image1 imdiff
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type `enter code here`NiftiIO::NiftiException: Error: cant open file imdiff.nii.gz
Abort trap: 6
```

I expected that image1 would be subtracted from image0 and that that new image would be called imdiff

Comment: Hi Sophie, welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). This questions need to have better tags on it, since whilst it is running under Unix, it isn't a Unix specific question. The question centers around the use of FSLMATHS library. The output won't be found since the software terminated abnormally. Need to know what images image0 and image1 represent and a way for others to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had the same error and came across your post when trying to fix it

```
NBrMBP:intro colette$ fslmaths image0 -sub image1 imdiff
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NiftiException: Error: cant open file imdiff.nii.gz
```

Luckily my supervisor was able to help.
I did not have permission to the directory/folders/files that I downloaded from the FSL tutorial website, but worked after I changed the permissions

1. `cd` to the folder that has the files you are trying to use (for me this was a folder called preCourse)
2. use the command: `ls –la` 
   This lists details of the files in the directory. In the left hand column it shows the permissions with `dr-xr-xr-x@`  which means I only had permission to read the files.
   e.g:

   `NBrMBP:preCourse colette$ ls -la
   total 16

   dr-xr-xr-x@  3 colette  staff   102 21 Jul  2017 fmri
   dr-xr-xr-x@ 23 colette  staff   782 21 Jul  2017 intro`
3. Use the command: `chmod u+w <directoryname>` 
   Run this from the folder above the one you would need permissions from. (u=user w = writing permissions)

e.g `NBrMBP:preCourse colette$ chmod u+w intro`

4. Now use `ls –la` again, it should now show `drwxr-xr-x@` in the left hand column i
   e.g.:

   `NBrMBP:preCourse colette$ ls -la
   total 16
   drwx------@  5 colette  staff   170  8 Jan 11:55 .
   drwxr-xr-x   4 colette  staff   136  8 Jan 11:55 ..
   -rw-r--r--@  1 colette  staff  6148  8 Jan 11:55 .DS_Store
   drwxr-xr-x@  3 colette  staff   102 21 Jul  2017 fmri
   drwxr-xr-x@ 26 colette  staff   884  8 Jan 15:51 intro`

*Note you may need admin permissions on your computer to be able to change the permissions of the read/write/executability of the files.

Hope this helps anyone else who searched the error code!